# Html input doesn't accept any character in mobile in a specific page

Tags: html

I have a login page with 2 inputs, one for username and an other one for password, but in mobile phone browser I can't type inside the inputs. !!!
What do you thing?
Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ssss</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/persianDatePicker-default.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/persianDatepicker.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="js/num2str.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <img src="pic/logo.png" id="logo" />
        <div id="topBar">

        </div>  
        <div id="menuWrapper"></div>
<div id="login">
                <form action="index.php?login" method="post" class="loginForm">
                <input placeholder="username" type="text" id="username" name="username" /><br /><br />
                <input placeholder="password" type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:
I had this 3 lines code in my css file that caused this issue, I removed them and very things got true.
Here is the code:

```
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
-moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with: you lock a `</script>` without having opened before in:

```
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's a copy/past mistake, actually its ok and there is not </script> in my code.